# How to keep just the date YYYY-MM-DD in pandas.Timestamp.today() function?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, time-series

I want to get rid of the time in today() function:

Today= pd.Timestamp.today()
print(Today)

result = **2020-02-28** 12:10:11.862889

I just want the **2020-02-28** and get rid of the 12:10:11.862889

Thank's!

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('now').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` or `pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: It works! Awesome!

Comment: Can you write it as an answer please?